# PHP revert html special characters in txt file

Tags: php, replace, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I currently have a txt file that looks like this:

```
ABCDEF
Blah&#8217;s Test
12344
Blah&#8217;s Test
Testing
```

I tried to convert the special characters into their actual characters, so for example, I attempted make the original txt file into this:

```
ABCDEF
Blah's Test
12344
Blah's Test
Testing
```

To do this I used `html_entity_decode()` however, instead of my expected results, I'm getting something like:

```
ABCDEF
Blahâ€™s Test
12344
Blahâ€™s Test
Testing
```

How can I fix my code to do what I want?

My code:

```
<?php
$items = file_get_contents('test1.txt');
$items = html_entity_decode($items);
file_put_contents("test2.txt", $items);
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php (htmlspecialchars_decode())

Comment: @DavidWilkins Yes, I've already tried that, it still does not work.

Comment: Have you considered str_replace() prior to adding the values to change the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the character set

```
html_entity_decode($a, ENT_QUOTES, 'cp1251');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the character encoding option.

```
html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP are you using?

In versions prior to 5.4.0 The html_entity_decode() function defualts to ISO-8859-1 encoding. In version 5.4.0 and later it defaults to UTF-8 encoding. I suspect you are using an earlier version than 5.4.0. As a result, the UTF-8 characters you're using are not being properly decoded.

Try passing UTF-8 as a second parameter. See here for more info: http://www.php.net/html_entity_decode

Comment: Ahh, I believe that must be it. I need to upgrade my version of PHP.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to upgrade your verison of PHP to fix this. You just need to pass in optional params to specify character set. See the answer below mine from @MisterKatiyar